# Hugs, functions and how it calculate

Tags: haskell

I have an input:

```
 [ 8 `div` 2 + 1 .. ] !! 2 : [ 1 .. 3 ]
```

the Output is:

```
 [7,1,2,3]
```

But.. what does Haskell calculate first?

I don't know the priority, where's the 7 from?

Comment: I think you mean `\`div\``.

Comment: @rightfold: it's appropriate to simply edit a question in such cases, rather than commenting. `'div'` _obviously_ can't be meant, and wasn't what the OP originally used, otherwise they couldn't have obtained that result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question sort of contains two questions, so I'll do my best to briefly answer both.

### 1. Order of operations in Haskell

Given an expression such as `2 + 4 * 3`, will Haskell calculate `2+4` first and then multiply it by three, or will it calculate `4*3` before that and then add two? As you might have guessed, `4*3` goes first.

How do you know which comes first? You look in the documentation and/or source code for the operator in question. Or you can figure it out experimentally. In your example of

```
[ 8 `div` 2 + 1 .. ] !! 2 : [ 1 .. 3 ]
```

I know just from experience that if you were to put parentheses everywhere, they would look like this:

```
([ ((8 `div` 2) + 1) .. ] !! 2) : [ 1 .. 3 ]
```

#### Finding out precedence

In order to figure this out properly though, you need to open up `ghci`, and type

```
:info (+)
```

for example, and it will say something along the lines of

```
infixl 6 (+)
```

If we do this for the other operators as well, we can build us a neat table.

```
infixl 7 `div`
infixl 6 +
infixr 5 :
infixl 9 !!
```

`ghci` didn't say anything for `(!!)`, But I went to the [source code for list operations in the Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-List.html) and found the line that said exactly what I showed in the table. Then you can assume that lists work a little like parentheses, so things inside the `[]` square brackets go before the things outside of them.

#### How precedence works

Now, the number before the operator name in the `infix` declarations says how high precedence the operator has – the higher the number, the more it goes before other things. In this case, for example, we had

```
infixl 7 `div`
infixl 6 +
```

This means that `` `div` `` goes before `+`, and indeed, in the expression

```
8 `div` 2 + 1
```

we find that Haskell calculates the result as

```
(8 `div` 2) + 1
```

because `` `div` `` had a higher precedence. If you do this for the rest of the expression, you will end up with the same parentheses as I did in the beginning of this answer.

You usually don't have to care very much though, because the more Haskell you write, the more are you going to get a feeling for how it all works out. And most often, if you get it wrong, you will also get a type error to remind you that you got it wrong. When in doubt, try both with parentheses and without in `ghci` and see which one gives the right answer.

### 2. Order of calculation in Haskell

Up to this point I have answered the question "how is an expression interpreted by Haskell?" The order in which it is *actually calculated* is a whole different question. Most programming languages calculate the inner parentheses first – Haskell does quite the opposite!

Given the expression

```
([ ((8 `div` 2) + 1) .. ] !! 2) : [ 1 .. 3 ]
```

Haskell will at the start just see it as

```
<something>
```

then when you ask for the value, it will groan a little and realise it's saying

```
<something> : <something>
```

It will realise it needs to calculate further to give you a value, so it will expand it into

```
(<something> !! <something>) : [ 1 .. 3 ]
```

(By the way, these `<something>`s are usually called *thunks* by Haskell people.) Then it will have to go even deeper, turning it into

```
([ <something> .. ] !! 2) : [ 1 .. 3 ]
```

Then it needs the second element of this list, so it will expand as much of the list as it has to.

```
([ <something>
 , (<something> + 1)
 , (<something> + 2) .. ] !! 2) : [ 1 .. 3 ]
```

Then it can reduce the `!!`, giving back the third element of the list (which has index 2), so the whole list disappears and is replaced by the third element.

```
(<something> + 2) : [ 1 .. 3 ]
```

and then it can reduce the `:`, so the result is a single list.

```
[ <something + 2>, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

At this point, it finally has to figure out what that `<something>` is, so it goes back to the definition of it and expands it into

```
[ (<something> + 1) + 2, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

and then

```
[ ((8 `div` 2) + 1) + 2, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

and *then* it starts calculating the actual value of the first element, giving you

```
[ (4 + 1) + 2, 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 5 + 2, 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 7, 1, 2, 3 ]
```

The thing to take away from this is that Haskell tries to *not* calculate any value unless it absolutely has to. It tries to, as far as possible, only work with descriptions of values, and not any actual values. It's in the *very end* that it performs all the calculations necessary.

If you didn't ask for the first value of the list, it would *never have gotten calculated*.

This is what's meant by "lazy evaluation."

Comment: The only proper answer so far.

Answer (score 4):

```
[ 8 `div` 2 + 1 .. ] !! 2 : [ 1 .. 3 ]
[ 4 + 1 .. ] !! 2 : [ 1 .. 3 ]
[ 5 .. ] !! 2 : [ 1 .. 3 ]
7 : [ 1 .. 3 ]
[7,1,2,3]
```

Function application is from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

`` 8 `div` 2 ≡ 4 ``, so `` [ 8 `div` 2 + 1 .. ] `` means `[ 5 .. ]`. This is an infinite list `[5,6,7,8 ..]`.

`list !! n` – take *n*-th element (from 0) from the list, so `[5 .. ] !! 2 ≡ 7`.